# DRY Routes for single controller Rails 4 STI Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, single-table-inheritance

I have an STI model that has over 20 subclasses and I need to point them all to the parent controller in my routes.  I have been defining each one in the routes, but this is really inefficient and not DRY. This is how it looks now.

```
  resources :red_master_models, :controller => 'master_models'
  resources :green_master_models, :controller => 'master_models'
  resources :yellow_master_models, :controller => 'master_models'
  resources :purple_master_models, :controller => 'master_models'
  resources :orange_master_models, :controller => 'master_models'
  resources :grey_master_models, :controller => 'master_models'
  resources :indigo_master_models, :controller => 'master_models'
  resources :blue_master_models, :controller => 'master_models'
```

I feel like I should be able to loop all the subclasses and define it more simply. This is what I've tried...but it doesn't work.

```
  MasterModel.subclasses.each do |master_model|
    resources master_model.name.underscore.to_sym, :controller => 'master_models'
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

It probably doesn't work because the subclasses for MasterModel haven't been auto-loaded yet, so that method just returns an empty array. Try explicitly requiring the models above your loop and see what happens.

Comment: What is the syntax to require my models?

Comment: I've searched for how to explicitly require the models and I'm at a loss. Do you have any insight?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your first comment. Just for purposes of testing the theory, I would first do this:

`puts 'here'
MasterModel.subclasses.each do |master_model|
    puts master_model.to_s
    resources master_model.name.underscore.to_sym, :controller => 'master_models'
end
`

Comment: I seem to not know how to format comments here. Anyway, the idea is to do two things: 1) Verify the loop is not running because there are no subclasses. Then, 2) just do a full `require /absolute/path/to/one/model` in routes.rb. After step 2, the `puts` from step 1 should show the single model that you've required.